# Chart Display after plot error

Tags: c#, charts

I have a program to plot chart but now there is a problem where sometimes the chart does not show fully. Is there any way to fix it?

What I expect it to be:

[image: What I expect it to be]

Currently, the problem faced:

[image: Currently, the problem faced]

code, where i key, generate the graph

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[0].Value.ToString();     // Start of X-T/B
        float x1 = float.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[0].Value.ToString());  // Get of X-T/B Value
       var Chart = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        Chart.AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        Chart.AxisY.Title = "Average";
        var Chart1 = chart2.ChartAreas[0];
        Chart1.AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        Chart1.AxisY.Title = "Range";

        Chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        Chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        Chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        Chart1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        Chart1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        Chart1.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        this.chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
        this.chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
        this.chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

        chart2.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
        chart2.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
        chart2.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource
```

double lclx = (Convert.ToDouble(label22.Text));
            double uclx = (Convert.ToDouble(label21.Text));

```
        double lclR = (Convert.ToDouble(label25.Text));  Caculation
        double uclR = (Convert.ToDouble(label24.Text));Caculation
        double y = lclx - 0.02;Caculation
        double z = uclx + 0.02;Caculation

        double p = lclR - 0.04;Caculation
        if (lclR <= 0.00)Caculation
        {
            p = 0.00;Caculation
        }



        double b = uclR + 0.04;
        Chart.AxisX.Minimum = 1;  // Descriptions 
        Chart.AxisX.Maximum = 31;     // Descriptions 

        Chart.AxisY.Minimum = y;         // Descriptions 
        Chart.AxisY.Maximum = z;           // Descriptions 
        Chart.AxisX.Interval = 1;                // Descriptions 
        Chart.AxisY.Interval = 0.02;                  // Descriptions 

        Chart1.AxisX.Minimum = 1;               // Descriptions 
        Chart1.AxisX.Maximum = 31;                    // Descriptions 

        Chart1.AxisY.Minimum = p;                   // Descriptions 
        Chart1.AxisY.Maximum = b;                       // Descriptions 
        Chart1.AxisX.Interval = 1;                         // Descriptions 
        Chart1.AxisY.Interval = 0.05;

        this.chart1.Series.Clear();
        this.chart1.Series.Dispose();
        chart2.Series.Clear();
        chart2.Series.Dispose();

         this.chart1.Series.Add("X-T/B");
        this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].Color = Color.Black;
        this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].BorderWidth = 3;
        this.chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        chart2.Series.Add("Range");
        chart2.Series["Range"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart2.Series["Range"].Color = Color.Black;
        chart2.Series["Range"].BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

        this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
        this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].MarkerSize = 10;
        this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].MarkerColor = Color.Blue;
        chart2.Series["Range"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
        chart2.Series["Range"].MarkerSize = 10;
        chart2.Series["Range"].MarkerColor = Color.Blue;



         this.chart1.Series["X-T/B"].Points.AddXY(1, x1);
```

Comment: Did you set the y-axis-maximum ?

Comment: Nope i need to let it Constantly change accordingly

Comment: Can you set a border and show the whole chart? Also show the code that add the points! Any extra chartareas? If so: Show how they are created including the Position!

Comment: Why do you write you didn't set the y-axis maximum, when you clearly do set it in your code??

Comment: How to set border? Any Help u can give me

Comment: Set BorderLinecolor and BoderLineDashStyle. But again: You do set the y-axis.Maximum! What is the error? That the data don't fit? That could be because they are greater than the Maximum. Or is it that the top looks cut off? That could be that because it is overlaid..

Comment: Any way to fix it ?

Comment: What??? You never properly answer my questions. How could I help you?

Comment: I had set my Y Min and Y Max but there again I am guessing that the chart can be displayed fully because i had to put both of the chart together , does the chart size matter